# How to translate Mongodb aggregate command in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am running the  following command in the mongo CLI to identify 2 or more docs that are in the collection with same date of creation.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({$group: { _id: "$date", count: { $sum: 1 }, docs:{ $push : "$_id" }}}, { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } })
```

However, when I try to run this from a Python script with following lines, I am getting errors.

```
collection = db[collections_name]
collection.aggregate({"$group": { '_id': "$date", 'count': { "$sum": 1 }, 'docs':{ "$push" : "$_id" }}}, { "$match": { 'count': { "$gt": 1 } } })
```

Unable to understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html. This will help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipeline operation must be passed in as a python list

```
collection.aggregate([{"$group": { '_id': "$date", 'count': { "$sum": 1 }, 'docs':{ "$push" : "$_id" }}}, { "$match": { 'count': { "$gt": 1 } } }])
```